# How can we find the bar_index of the lowest and RED bar within last 5 bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I would like to find the bar_index of the lowest RED (close < open) bar within last 5 bars, excluding the current bar.

I used the following code but it seems that it does not work correctly in some cases:

```
Check(no) =>
    minValue = lowest(5)[1]
    int find = na
    for i = 1 to no
    if (low[i] <= minValue) and (close[i] < open[i])
        find := i
    find
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use (Pinescript v5):

```
Check(no) =>
    Lowest_red_value = ta.highest(no) // Init to high value
    Bar_index_Lowest_red_bar = 0
    // Search for Red bar
    for i = 1 to no
        if close[i] < open[i]
            if low[i] < Lowest_red_value
                Lowest_red_value := low[i]
                Bar_index_Lowest_red_bar := bar_index - i
    Bar_index_Lowest_red_bar
```

Be carefull, if there is no Red bar in your 'no' previous bars, this function will return 0.

With this code you can get the bar_index of the lowest red bar as shown in this screenshot :

[image]

The code used for the example is :

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

Check(no) =>
    Lowest_red_value = ta.highest(no) // Init to high value
    Bar_index_Lowest_red_bar = 0
    // Search for Red bar
    for i = 1 to no
        if close[i] < open[i]
            if low[i] < Lowest_red_value
                Lowest_red_value := low[i]
                Bar_index_Lowest_red_bar := bar_index - i
    Bar_index_Lowest_red_bar

//plotshape(barstate.islast?close:na, "Lowest Red Bar", shape.triangledown, location.belowbar,color=color.red, offset=Check(5)-bar_index)
var label mark = na
barred = Check(5)
if barstate.islast
    label.delete(mark)
    if barred != 0
        mark := label.new(x=barred,y=ta.lowest(5), text="X",xloc=xloc.bar_index,color=color.red, style=label.style_label_up)
```

Comment: I tried your code but it does not work for some case, i.e. FETBUSD timeframe 4H at 9 Jan '23 11:00. Can you please check?

Comment: @CandyG80 I update my answer to show you the result and my answer.

Comment: Can you please see the [image](https://i.imgur.com/CkxVY1A.png)

Comment: @CandyG80 I update the answer (and record the low of the red bar, not the close). With the code in example, you can see WHERE the Check(no) find the lowest red bar (the label is a red cross)

Comment: It works perfectly. Can you please help me to extract that bar_index number? i.e bar_index[4] --> so I just want to get that number 4

Comment: @CandyG80 if the code answer your question, please accept the answer. For your new question, please open a new question, you will get help.

Comment: I will accept your answer. But my question and my original code is asking for that number, as you can see in my code. So I think that it's not necessary to open the new question to ask for the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251014/discussion-between-g-lebret-and-candyg80).

Comment: @CandyG80 the bar_index you are looking for (the lowest red bar bar index) is given you by the check(n) fonction directly.

Comment: I already know it. It's the "find := i" as I wrote in the original code at the question. I just wait you to add the code to your answer but then I decide to accept your answer without needing the updates.